# Tomcat port 80 doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Using Eclipse, I set up Tomcat Server 7 but seems another application is using the port 80? I got this message from the Tomcat Server:

> Port 80 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)

How do I close anything on the port 80 on Mac OS X ?

Comment: Why dont you just change the port tomcat is running? You can put it to run in port 8084.

Comment: You could use lsof -p :80 to know which process is running in port 80. Probably it is Apache.  kill -9 pid listed.

Comment: which command I can use in Terminal to stop anything used port 80. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use lsof -p :80 to know which process is running in port 80. Probably it is Apache. kill -9 pid listed.

EX:

```
 sudo kill -9 `lsof -t -i:80`
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is for http right? Tomcat's default is 8080. If there is something on a mac running on 80 it would be apache. Do you have personal websharing turned on? Would probably be better to use 8080.

Comment: websharing like what? I only use Safari for browsing! I feel like there must be a command I can write in Terminal so to stop anything use port 80

Comment: In older versions of the OS, under sharing in System Preferences, there was an option Web Sharing and turning that on would start apache.